# How do I remove the navbar in Flutter for Android

Tags: flutter

See image below, there is a semi transparent nav type bar by default when starting a fresh app on flutter dev that I wish to remove with no idea where to look in the docs.

[image: The problem]

Comment: can you please provide the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set its color to transparent like this:

```
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,);
```

Or you can hide it completely like this:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

Comment: SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]); Do not solve the problem permanently. If you close and open your application the navigation bar will appear again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Then where you need you can write the below code. Also, if you need throughout the app the you can write it in `void main()`.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
```

Depending on your need you can change Brightness for statusBar as well as its icons.

Comment: Hey Vaishnav Datir, the status bar appears again after you open keyboard, navigating to another page or opening the app again. This answer is not permanently. We are looking for permanent solution.